# Как иметь доступ к внешним библиотекам в Python?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

Я делаю программу для macOS, которая использует pydub и ffmpeg. Когда я запускаю её через терминал или компилирую в исполняемый файл без расширения, то она работает правильно. Когда-же я запускаю через IDLE или компилирую в .app, то ffmpeg работать перестаёт. На других ОС всё работает.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы он работал?

Comment: Что конкретно означает «ffmpeg работать перестаёт», в чём это проявляется, какие-то ошибки или как?

Comment: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)

Такое-же происходит, когда ffmpeg не установлен вовсе.